# Nested 'if'-'else' statements

Tags: c#, switch-statement, if-statement

I have code that's very messy with the `if` - `else` if checks it is doing. The amount of branching and nested branching is quite big (over 20 if - else if and nested too). It's making my code harder to read and will probably be a performance hog. My application checks for a lot of conditions it gets from the user and so the application must check all the time for different situations, for example:

If the textbox text is not 0, continue with the next...

```
if ((StartInt != 0) && (EndInt != 0))   
{
```

And then here it checks to see whether the user have choosen dates:

```
if ((datePickerStart.SelectedDate == null) || (datePickerEnd.SelectedDate == null)) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Choose Dates");
}
```

Here, if the datepickers aren't null it continues with code...

```
else if ((datePickerStart.SelectedDate != null) && (datePickerEnd.SelectedDate != null))
{
    // CONDITIONS FOR SAME STARTING DAY AND ENDING DAY.
    if (datePickerStart.SelectedDate == datePickerEnd.SelectedDate)
    {
        if (index1 == index2)
        {
            if (StartInt == EndInt)
            {
                if (radioButton1.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    printTime3();
                }
                else
                {
                    printTime();
                }
            }
```

This is just a small part of the checks being made. Some of them are functionals and some are for input validation stuff.

Is there any way to make it more readable and less of a performance hog?

Comment: Maybe you should do Validation's in front of the Method or Event if you're doing it within ,like if(dtp.SelectedDate == null) return; than proceed with Information handling.

Comment: I have a strong feeling SelectedDate is from a calender control, those can never be null, you need to check `datePickerStart.SelectedDate == DateTime.MinValue` instead.

Comment: The code is working well thats not my problem. the problem i'm reffering to is the readability and performance of such complex if else branching

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not that of a performance hog. A great blog post on how to fix those common problems is *[Flattening Arrow Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)*.

Comment: That looks like what I need I will soon check it out and post back

Answer (score 3):

I see here some mix in validation. Try to move one fields from others, and validate them separately, something like this:

```
if (StartInt == 0 || EndInt == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Choose Ints");
    return;
}
if (datePickerStart.SelectedDate == null || datePickerEnd.SelectedDate == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Choose Dates");
    return;
}
```

In this approach you'll always say to the user what he did wrong, and your code is much simpler.

More information from [Jeff's blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)

Comment: the if ((StartInt != 0) && (EndInt != 0))   
{

is not for checking if the user inserted ints. its for checking if the input on 2 textboxs is 0 or not. if it is, then do something, else do something else.

like I said
some of the if else statements are for input validations but most of them are for condition checks.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to refactor by encapsulating *complex* conditions in the following way:

```
public bool DateRangeSpecified
{
  get 
  {
    return (datePickerStart.SelectedDate != null) 
           && 
           (datePickerEnd.SelectedDate != null)
           && StartInt != 0 && EndInt != 0; 
  }
}
```

and then using these "condition facade" properties

Answer (score 0):

Use the `return` statement to stop the execution of a block.

For instance,

```
void Test()
{
    if (StartInt==0 || EndInt==0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (datePickerStart.SelectedDate == null || datePickerEnd.SelectedDate == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Choose Dates");
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some slight refactoring makes it easier to read to my eyes. I removed extraneous brackets and consolidated multiple IF statements that are really just AND logic.

```
if (StartInt == 0 || EndInt == 0)    
    return;
if (datePickerStart.SelectedDate == null || datePickerEnd.SelectedDate == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Choose Dates");  
    return;           
}
if (datePickerStart.SelectedDate != null 
    && datePickerEnd.SelectedDate != null
    && datePickerStart.SelectedDate == datePickerEnd.SelectedDate
    && index1 == index2
    && StartInt == EndInt)
{
    if (radioButton1.IsChecked == true)
        printTime3();
    else
        printTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own predicates or generic functions with meaningful names and encapsulate you logic into those.

Here is a code example for some predicates:

```
public Predicate<DateTime> CheckIfThisYear = a => a.Year == DateTime.Now.Year;
public Func<DateTime, int, bool> CheckIfWithinLastNDays = (a, b) => (DateTime.Now - a).Days < b;
```

Now you can easily write in your code

```
if (CheckIfThisYear(offer) && CheckIfWithinLastNDays(paymentdate,30)) ProcessOrder();
```

Consider using generic delegates, like `Func<>` and `Delegate<>` for writing small blocks of your conditions using lambda-expressions -- it will both save the space and makes your code much more human-readable.