# C# Nested If Statements in TDD and Code Metrics

Tags: c#, .net

```
public void AccessPermissions(User user)
{
   if (user.Age >= 18)
   {
      if (user.IsRegistred)
      {
         if (user.IsPowerfull)
         {
             AcessGrantLevel3();
         }
         else
         {
             AccessGrantLevel2();
         }
      }
      else
      {
         AccessGrantLevel1();
      }
   }
   else
   {
       AcceessDenied();
   }
}
```

According to code metrics measurement this function is very bad and according to the clean code developemnt this function is bad for testing.
What can I do to make Code Metrics and TDD happy? Is nested If statements always bad?

Comment: This questions belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Show the link if this true?!

Comment: There are a lot better ways to build this.  Factory or Strategy pattern would a better way to go.

Comment: I would suggest you make AccessGrantLevel() a function with a parameter that can be 0 (Access Denied) up to 3 (Registered & Powerful

Comment: @Sparky this sounds very good and good for SOLID can you make a small example for me please?

Comment: @paqogomez I know Stratgy pattern when I Need differents implementation for same algorithm but how can I apply it here?

Comment: There's lots of questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348472/nested-if-else-statements

Comment: @DanielA.White Show the link if this true?!

Comment: @user814064 My question how to improve it for TDD and code metrics!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Here is one approach**

```
public void AccessPermissions(User user)
{
    int UserLevel = 0;

UserLevel += (user.Age>=18) ? 1:0;      // Add 1 if user is over 18
UserLevel += (user.IsIsRegistred) ? 1:0;    // If registered, add another 1
UserLevel += (user.IsPowerFull) ? 1:0;      // Add another 1 if powerful

AccessGrantLevel( UserLevel );
}
```

Comment: That is not good, as someone who is under 18 but is registered will have the same user level as someone who is over 18 but not registered.

Comment: Looking very good open closed principle thanks a lot!

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i will modfiy the code I just want the concept!

Comment: This methodology has the potential to suddenly break completely if the access level system gets any more complicated. What's wrong with simply mapping levels to an enum and passing that in?

Comment: Ant P Enum with a switch is not a bad idea but this will hide the function complexity @Sparky idea is really good!

Comment: @BassamAlugili It really isn't. This method makes no sense. It works for this particular instance but is totally unmaintainable and unscalable. This is a hack.

Comment: I agree, this is an example of one approach, but I put it together more to demonstrate, not to provide actual.

Comment: Why would you knowingly post bad code as a suggested resolution to a problem?

Comment: @AntP I will redesign the classes I think this will be best Approach! Thanks this Approach is really not open for extenation

Comment: AntP, it is not bad code, it simply encourages encapsulation of the AccessGrantLevel() into a function, rather than a series of individual function calls.  The code above focused on determining the parameter and let's the function do the work.   I would not suggest it for more complex condition sets, but for small sets like described, it is a reasonable approach..

Comment: This approach is in fact some kind of `implicit implementation of enumeration`, you should use different added constants, we have to calculate those constants so that any combination (the sum) of the constants is not duplicated with any particular constant.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void AccessPermissions(User user)
{
    if(user.Age<18)
    {
        AccessDenied();
        return;
    }
    if(user.IsPowerfull && user.IsRegistered)
    {
        AccessGrantLevel3();
        return;
    }
    if(user.IsRegistered)
    {
        AccessGrantLevel2();
        return;
    }
    AccessGrantLevel1();
    return;
}
```

Comment: This misses braces `{ ... }` or else it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the logic like this:

```
public void AccessPermissions(User user)
{
    if (user.Age < 18)
    {
        AcceessDenied();
    }
    else if (!user.IsRegistred)
    {
        AccessGrantLevel1();
    }
    else if (!user.IsPowerfull)
    {
        AcessGrantLevel2();
    }
    else
    {
        AccessGrantLevel3();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can easily be re-written without nesting.

```
public void AccessPermissions(User user)
{
   if (user.Age < 18)
   {
       AcceessDenied();
   }
   else if (!user.IsRegistred)
   {
       AccessGrantLevel1();
   }
   else if (user.IsPowerfull)
   {
       AcessGrantLevel3();
   }
   else
   {
       AccessGrantLevel2();
   }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of what I wrote 30 seconds prior ... =/

Comment: The "another answer has been posted" bottom bar popped up just as I clicked submit. Thems the breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of preference, but most people consider nested if statements to be less readable and harder to maintain, because the code that is to be executed is far away from the statement that caused it.

By reversing the condition of the If statement, you can move the execution logic closer to the condition.  consider:

```
public void AccessPermissions(User user)
{
    if (!(user.Age >= 18))
    {
        AcccessDenied();
    }
    else if (!user.IsRegistered)
    {
        AccessGrantLevel1();
    }
    else if (!user.IsPowerfull)
    {
        AccessGrantLevel2();
    }
    else
    {
        AccessGrantLevel3();
    }
}
```

Ultimately, any of the multiple examples on this page of other approaches would work with a bit of tweaking... the concept still stands that your goal should be to reduce or eliminate nesting by inverting your conditions.

Comment: Loving this: "Update coming to illustrate a better approach."

Comment: I made the post but needed a minute to type out the code logic, between the post and the update 2 other people posted the same thing :)

Comment: So every user should be granted level3 access? Oops.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `if(!user.Age >= 18)` will error out without a parentheses `if(!(user.Age >= 18))`

Comment: and catching some of my own typos along the way... been a long day already.

Comment: @AndrewCounts still won't work, you need to use `else if` or put return statements in each block. Otherwise someone who is not powerful and is not registered will have both `AccessGrantLevel1()` and `AccessGrantLevel2()` called.